# Fresh install of visual studio 2015 community, exception when load Team Explorer

Tags: visual-studio-2015

I just installed VS 2015 community on a brand new laptop, it was the first thing I installed. VS opens fine, but when I open the Team Explorer tool window I get this error showing in it:

```html
System.ArgumentException: Object of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Lazy`2[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WinForms.PermissionRow,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.Avatars.DefaultIOHandler]]' cannot be converted to type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Lazy`2[Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.ITeamExplorerNavigationItem,Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.ITeamExplorerNavigationItemMetadata]]'.
   at System.RuntimeType.TryChangeType(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, Boolean needsSpecialCast)
   at System.RuntimeType.CheckValue(Object value, Binder binder, CultureInfo culture, BindingFlags invokeAttr)
   at System.Reflection.MethodBase.CheckArguments(Object[] parameters, Binder binder, BindingFlags invokeAttr, CultureInfo culture, Signature sig)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.InvokeArgumentsCheck(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimeMethodInfo.Invoke(Object obj, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] parameters, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, BindingFlags invokeAttr, Binder binder, Object[] index, CultureInfo culture)
   at System.Reflection.RuntimePropertyInfo.SetValue(Object obj, Object value, Object[] index)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.SetImportingMember(Object part, MemberInfo member, Object value)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.GetValueForImportSite(RuntimePartLifecycleTracker importingPartTracker, RuntimeImport import)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.RuntimeExportProviderFactory.RuntimeExportProvider.RuntimePartLifecycleTracker.SatisfyImports()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.SatisfyImmediateImports()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveNext(PartLifecycleState nextState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.MoveToState(PartLifecycleState requiredState)
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.PartLifecycleTracker.GetValueReadyToExpose()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass53_0.<CreateExport>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass55_0.<CreateExportFactoryExport>b__1()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.ExportProvider.<>c__DisplayClass54_0.<CreateExportFactory>b__0()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.DelegateServices.<>c__DisplayClass2_0`1.<As>b__0()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory`1.CreateExport()
   at Microsoft.VisualStudio.Composition.NetFxAdapters.MefV1ExportProvider.ComposablePartDefinitionForExportFactory.CreatePart()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ExportFactoryCreator.LifetimeContext.GetExportLifetimeContextFromExport[T](Export export)
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ReflectionModel.ExportFactoryCreator.<>c__DisplayClass6_0`2.<CreateStronglyTypedExportFactoryOfTM>b__0()
   at System.ComponentModel.Composition.ExportFactory`1.CreateExport()
   at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls.WPF.TeamExplorer.Framework.TeamExplorerSectionHost.Create()
```

Does anyone know how to fix this, I tried reinstalling and it still causes this error.

Comment: It was related to an extension. What threw me off that trail was the fact that even after disabling the extension it still caused the error. 

After  the refresh, and in a working state with the extension installed, I turned the previous setting back on and the error showed up again.

This particular problem was that the extension was compiled against the downloaded VS SDK about a month ago and VS came with (I think) new versions, a quick resetting the references, a recompile and everything is working ok so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At least the reference **Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Controls** and so the **ITeamExplorerNavigationItem** seems not to exist anymore in Visual Studio 2015.

I just tried to create an extension for the Team Explorer and get stuck at this point.